# "Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict" error while converting xsd to java objects using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall elements of xds file to java oblects. I am using Jaxb mavan plugin and Eclipse IDE.
My .xsd file is can be found from

[EiPayload](http://docs.oasis-open.org/energyinterop/ei/v1.0/os/xsd/EiPayloads.xsd)

[EiEnrollment](http://docs.oasis-open.org/energyinterop/ei/v1.0/os/xsd/EiEnrollment.xsd)

[EiClasses](http://docs.oasis-open.org/energyinterop/ei/v1.0/os/xsd/EIClasses.xsd)

Here is my file structure and error,
[image]

Need some help to debug this error..!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I am a lead dev of the [ogc-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) and the [w3c-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas) projects.

You have problems with GML 3.2.1 and XLink 1.0. I've implemented bindings for these schemas in the [ogc-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) and the [w3c-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas) project. Here you go:

- [gml-v_3_2_1.xjb](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/gml/3.2.1/src/main/resources/gml-v_3_2_1.xjb)
- [xlink-v_1_0.xjb](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas/blob/master/xlink/1999/src/main/resources/xlink-v_1_0.xjb)

But better use the [provided JAR artifacts](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jvnet/ogc/gml-v_3_2_1/2.5.2/) as [episodes](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Episodes).